# How to Get Unique Latitude and Longitude Pair from List of Dictionary without Numpy?

Tags: python, unique

I have this list of dict:

```
position_list = [
   {'position.latitude': -1, 'position.longitude': -1}, 
   {'position.latitude': -3, 'position.longitude': 2}, 
   {'position.latitude': -3, 'position.longitude': 2}, 
   {'position.latitude': -4, 'position.longitude': 5},
   {'position.latitude': 5, 'position.longitude': -4}
]
```

What I want is this:

```
position_list = [
   {'position.latitude': -1, 'position.longitude': -1}, 
   {'position.latitude': -3, 'position.longitude': 2}, 
   {'position.latitude': -4, 'position.longitude': 5}
   {'position.latitude': 5, 'position.longitude': -4}
]
```

I can't use the NumPy library because I have to do this not only in Python.
How do I achieve this?

**EDIT**
The order should be preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest approach

```
>>> new = []
>>> for i in position_list:
...     if i not in new:
...         new.append(i)
...

>>> new
[{'position.latitude': -1, 'position.longitude': -1}, {'position.latitude': -3, 'position.longitude': 2}, {'position.latitude': -4, 'position.longitude': 5}, {'position.latitude': 5, 'position.longitude': -4}]
```

**Update:** Order is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a frozenset() for this

```
In [1]: position_list = [
   ...:    {'position.latitude': -1, 'position.longitude': -1},
   ...:    {'position.latitude': -3, 'position.longitude': 2},
   ...:    {'position.latitude': -3, 'position.longitude': 2},
   ...:    {'position.latitude': -4, 'position.longitude': 5},
   ...:    ]

In [2]: position_list
Out[2]: 
[{'position.latitude': -1, 'position.longitude': -1},
 {'position.latitude': -3, 'position.longitude': 2},
 {'position.latitude': -3, 'position.longitude': 2},
 {'position.latitude': -4, 'position.longitude': 5}]

In [3]: [dict(s) for s in set(frozenset(d.items()) for d in position_list)]
Out[3]: 
[{'position.longitude': 5, 'position.latitude': -4},
 {'position.longitude': 2, 'position.latitude': -3},
 {'position.latitude': -1, 'position.longitude': -1}]
```

Comment: I would use OrderedSet instead of a set: 
[dict(s) for s in OrderedSet(frozenset(d.items()) for d in position_list)]

to achieve an ordered list;

Comment: @Daniel111 I am not aware that Python has an `OrderedSet` what library is this from?

Comment: I use it by :

`from setuptools._vendor.ordered_set import OrderedSet`